# How to implement non personalized ads in Adsense ?

Tags: web, ads, adsense

I dont get it, they say to Set the value:

```
(adsbygoogle=window.adsbygoogle||[]).requestNonPersonalizedAds=1
```

But where do I set it, if i have ad like this:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/
pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- leaderboard -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
data-ad-slot="1234567890"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ad code for non-personalized ads :

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Your site title</title>
</head>
<body>

<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>(adsbygoogle=window.adsbygoogle||[]).requestNonPersonalizedAds=1;</script>
// The line above makes sure you are requesting non-personalized ads. It needs to come before you use <script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script> and it suffices to have one such line per page.
<!-- One test unit for GDPR -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"     style="display:inline-block;width:970px;height:250px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pubxxx"
    data-ad-slot="slot_id">
</ins>

<!-- Another test unit for GDPR -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"     style="display:inline-block;width:250px;height:250px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pubxxx"
    data-ad-slot="slot_id">
</ins>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
// This triggers the ad request.

</body>
</html>
```

See https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9042142?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you can add this to the code you posted and whether it works or not, but here is a short guide to do this from your Google account:

To opt out of showing user-based ads:

1. Sign in to your AdSense account.
2. In the left navigation panel, click **Allow & block ads > All my sites > Ad serving**.
3. Under '**Personalised ads**', use the control (switch) to opt out of user-based ads.

Source: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/142293?hl=en-GB

Answer (score -1):

Like @Minister said, you can turn off personalized ads for your whole account.

However, it will not disable **Remarketing** ads ... so if you went to Sears, you will see ads from sears..

Unfortunately u can't turn of personal ads on site or ad unit level... its only for the whole account